# Run on condition with GitHub Actions

Tags: github-actions

Using GitHub Actions I have the following:

```
strategy:
  matrix:
    projects: ['src/Api', 'test/Web.Test']

steps:

  - name: Test
    run: dotnet test ...
```

How to run the action only if the matrix value has test?

Comment: ...did you try `if:`?

Comment: Or depending on context maybe you want to `exclude` that case from the matrix, or just leave it out to start with.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `if` condition to prevent a job from running unless a condition is met. GitHub Actions supports [expressions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions) and a set of [built-in functions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#functions) that you can use in expressions like `contains` or `startsWith`

define your condition under steps in your workflow file :

```
steps:
  - name: Test
    run: dotnet test
    if: matrix.projects == 'test/Web.Test'
```